# How to use any framework without CocoaPod in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am developing an iOS application using Swift language. I want to use some framework in this application. There are some frameworks which can be installed using CocoaPods, so is there any way to use those frameworks without Cocoapods? Can I add them directly to my project?

Thanks..!

Comment: Yes you can. Download it and add it to your project. Make sure to add all dependencies as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. go to source file and check there will be .h and .m file for objective c.drag that file into your project and import it into header class and as per need you can use it